# How to calculate the maximum number of meetings possible

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following interview problem

> Given two arrays firstDay and lastDay representing the intervals in days of possible meetings. Calculate the maximum number of meetings, **with only one meeting per day**.

**Example**:

Input:

> firstDay = [1, 1, 3]; lastDay= [1, 3, 3]

Output:

> 3

**Explanation**:

> Array interval[i] = [firstDay[i], lastDay[i]]

In the interval [0] = [1, 1], this meeting can only be held on day 1, so it will be the meeting on day 1;

In the interval [1] = [1, 3], this meeting can be held on days 1, 2 or 3, however day 1 is already busy and day 3 will interfere in the interval [2], leaving only day 2 for that meeting;

In the interval [2] = [3, 3], this meeting can only be held on day 3, so it will be the meeting on day 3;

**Solution: (Greedy algorithm)**

```java
    public static int countMeetings(List<Integer> firstDay, List<Integer> lastDay) {
        List<Interval> intervals = IntStream.range(0, firstDay.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> new Interval(firstDay.get(i), lastDay.get(i)))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Interval::getEnd))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Integer> meetings = new ArrayList<>();
        intervals.forEach(interval -> {
            for (int i = interval.getStart(); i <= interval.getEnd(); i++) {
                if (!meetings.contains(i)) {
                    meetings.add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        return meetings.size();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add info on the cases that do not work? I must say that I am a bit lost at what the arrays of the input exactly represent. Would be good to elaborate.

Comment: ok, I added an example where my code fails, the problem is that there can be only one meeting per day and intervals represent the possible days that a meeting can happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another Greedy algorithm.

The intervals are sorted according to the last day, then if equality according to the first day.

Then for each interval, we try to insert one of day of the interval in the set of meetings days. If we succeed, we increase the count of meetings.

Here is an implementation in C++ (Sorry, don't know java. Tell me if it is not clear)

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <vector>
#include    <set>
#include    <numeric>
#include    <algorithm>

int countMeetings (std::vector<int> &firstDay, std::vector<int> &lastDay) {
    int count = 0;
    int n = firstDay.size();
    std::vector<int> sort_index (n);
    std::iota (sort_index.begin(), sort_index.end(), 0);    // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    auto compar = [&firstDay, &lastDay] (int i, int j) {
        if (lastDay[i] != lastDay[j]) return lastDay[i] < lastDay[j];
        else return firstDay[i] < firstDay[j];
    };
    std::sort (sort_index.begin(), sort_index.end(), compar);

    std::set<int> meetings;

    for (auto i: sort_index) {      // we examine all intervals
        for (int j = firstDay[i]; j <= lastDay[i]; j++) {       // we examine all days of the intervl
            if (meetings.find(j) == meetings.end()) {       // j is a possible meeding date
                count++;
                meetings.insert (j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> firstDay = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3};
    std::vector<int> lastDay= {2, 2, 3, 4, 4};
    int count = countMeetings (firstDay, lastDay);
    std::cout << "number of meetings = " << count << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Apparently it solves the problem, I will write the solution in java and mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

This problem can be sloved using Greedy Algorithm :

```
static int getMaximumMeetings(List<Integer> start, List<Integer> timeTaken) {
    List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<>(); // create a List of Interval
    for (int i = 0; i < start.size(); i++) {
        list.add(new Interval(start.get(i), start.get(i) + timeTaken.get(i)));
    }
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.end)); // sort by finish times ascending

    int res = 0;
    int prevEnd = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // finish time of the previous meeting

    for (Interval i : list) {
        if (i.start >= prevEnd) { // is there a conflict with the previous meeting?
            res++;
            prevEnd = i.end; // update the previous finish time
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

***Just an example of some Interval entity:***

```
class Interval {
    int start;
    int end;    
    Interval(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

And if you have any doubt in the above code just comment down i always there to help you .

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, I added a test case where my code fails. The problem is that the interval does not exactly represent the beginning and the end of a meeting, for example the interval [1, 5] means that this meeting can take place between days 1 and 5 but only one meeting per day is allowed.

Comment: I will dinetly help you out . Let me check the code once and as you mentioned i'll take a look on that also .

Answer (score 0):

here we go i have tried in a very simple way , just give your input into my code and try to run the code hope you will get the desired o/p :

```
package testui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class testas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Integer> firstDay = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,1,3));
        ArrayList<Integer> lastDay = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,3,3));

        ArrayList<Interval> lol = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        for(int i=0;i<firstDay.size();i++) {
            lol.add(new Interval(firstDay.get(i),lastDay.get(i)));
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> check = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(Interval con : lol) {
            if(!check.contains(conobj.start) || !check.contains(conobj.end)) {
                for(Integer i=conobj.start;i<=conobj.end;i++) {
                    if(!check.contains(i))
                        check.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(check.size());



    }

}

class Interval{
    Integer start;
    Integer end;

    Interval(Integer start,Integer end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

If you still get any problem just reach out to me.

Comment: Idea is interesting, but still fails in the following test case firstDay = [1, 1, 1]; lastDay = [1, 2, 4]; Expected Output: 3. The meeting should only take place in one day.

Comment: ok,let me check why it is not working and i will get to u asap.

Comment: According to your test case explanation above the output of the following test case firstDay = [1, 1, 1]; lastDay = [1, 2, 4]; sholud be 4 and not 3. And the explanation what you have provided above according to that only the code is written by me and it is giving the expected result. Please do check with the explanation and also the test case.